# Test complete : How to log/print an object property value

Tags: automation, ui-automation, testcomplete

If I have an object like Browsers.Item("iexplore") and if it has a property called IsOpen ,

how to print it in test complete log
I am using Jscript for scripting
Test complete is version 9

Comment: What language are u talking about? js?

Comment: sorry missed to include that info , its JScript

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check whether a browser is running, you can do this in the following manner:

```
function test()
{
  var b = Sys.WaitBrowser("iexplore");
  if (b.Exists == true)
    Log.Message("Internet Explorer is running");
  else
    Log.Message("Internet Explorer is not running");
}
```

To get a value of an object's property, just address this property using the dot notation: object.property. To post this value to the test log, call the Log.Message method. Use the Log.Warning and Log.Error methods to post warnings and errors correspondingly.

```
Log.Message(obj.MyProperty);
```

Comment: For the moment , it is my requirement, but I also wanted to know a way to log/check the properties of any object during testing

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of these:

```
var yourObject = ..
console.info(yourObject);
console.log(yourObject);
console.log(yourObject.yourProperty);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about test complete and jscript ? It seems there is no keyword console available, i am getting an error. One more information - The test complete version is 9 . And I am writing this code within the test complete IDE

Comment: Oh i see, then, my bad, was thinking about something else which is irrelevant to your problem.